# display out of stock products progrmmatically in catalog product list block

Tags: magento-1.9, product, out-of-stock

I override `Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php` block and I want to display all products `out of stock` and if qty is 0 as well as  `in stock` products progrmmatically.

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
    {   
        parent::_getProductCollection();

        $this->_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter(
        array(
            array('attribute'=> 'is_in_stock','eq' => 0),
            array('attribute'=> 'is_in_stock','eq' => 1)
        )
        );

     echo "<pre>";
     print_r($this->_productCollection->getData());
     die();

        return $this->_productCollection;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just configure Magento to show out of stock products too?

Comment: You are right I respect your answer but I want to do with this way.Could you help me ?

Comment: Just get the collection without "addAttributeToFilter" and you will get both in stock and out of stock products. Do you need this?

Comment: I want out of stock  and in stock products collection.I tried this but I am getting collection in stock products.

Comment: Are you using flat catalog option in your Magento?

Comment: Check if it does work while flat catalog is disabled, i think your problem is in Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::isEnabledFlat

Comment: I do not know but it may be using flat catalog.

Comment: flat catalog is disable in system > configuration

Comment: Can you echo a ->getSelect() of your collection? Want to check something

Comment: system > configuration > inventory > display out of stock products. This is configuration option for display product. Where is located core file to check display out of stock product condition ?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::isEnabledFlat` since you are probably using the `flat catalog` option and you asked to hide out of stock products. So it is just not adding them to flat tables.

Just change your code removing the filter, you do **NOT** need it, it is useless:

```
->addAttributeToFilter(
        array(
            array('attribute'=> 'is_in_stock','eq' => 0),
            array('attribute'=> 'is_in_stock','eq' => 1)
        )
        ); // This is completely useless!
```

As you can see from the code `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection` constructor it uses a different resource model depending on your config:

```
protected function _construct()
    {
        if ($this->isEnabledFlat()) {
            $this->_init('catalog/product', 'catalog/product_flat');
        }
        else {
            $this->_init('catalog/product');
        }
        $this->_initTables();
    }
```

Now, if you see `isEnabledFlat` you will notice it checks for the admin store ID:

```
public function isEnabledFlat()
    {
        // Flat Data can be used only on frontend
        if (Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()) {
            return false;
        }
        $storeId = $this->getStoreId();
        if (!isset($this->_flatEnabled[$storeId])) {
            $flatHelper = $this->getFlatHelper();
            $this->_flatEnabled[$storeId] = $flatHelper->isAvailable() && $flatHelper->isBuilt($storeId);
        }
        return $this->_flatEnabled[$storeId];
    }
```

**What you can do is to fake the admin store:**

You have to rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer::getProductCollection` by adding this code at the very first lines:

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
```

**Otherwise:**

You could just rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection` and change the `isEnabledFlat` as follows:

```
protected function _construct()
    {
        if (false && $this->isEnabledFlat()) {
            $this->_init('catalog/product', 'catalog/product_flat');
        }
        else {
            $this->_init('catalog/product');
        }
        $this->_initTables();
    }
```

**If it oes not work**

Just check if you are getting filters from parent class.

Comment: I removed filter and follow your code changed isenabledflat but still not display out of stock products

Comment: So check you parent function, you probably have a filter there

Comment: In parent core class it default filter by category.

Comment: That's weird, you should see them just getting products collection.

Comment: P.S: use a foreach instead of "->getData()", I didn't see it before.

Comment: $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
  print_r($collection->getData()); If I put this code it works but this is not proper way because then it will not work for layer navigation because in block/product/list.php product collection attached with layered navigation

Comment: Oh, ok, sorry, I missed you were on List.php . Try just placing the admin code BEFORE the parent::_getProductCollection();

Comment: No its not working

Comment: yes I check all things but not work

Comment: Ok, try by using the admin code at beginning of Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer::getProductCollection . Of course you will have to rewrite the class, do not change the core files.